# Can't create CSS from SASS using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack

I've created a minimal file *global.sass* with the following contents (taken from [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide)).

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333
body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
```

In my *webpack.config.js* I have added the following loaders to module section (the second one taken from [here](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) as sugested on Webpack's page [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html)).

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel", exclude: /node_modules/ },
    { test: /\.sass$/, loader: "sass-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ }
  ]
},
```

In my gullible hopes I thought that running `webpack --progress` would produce a CSS file but apparently, nothing like that occurs. I only get a new version of *bundle.js* but the contents of the *global.sass* file aren't anywhere in it. No CSS file's produced at all.

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify: are you requiring/importing `global.sass` somewhere?

Comment: you need to import that file first

Comment: @mrlew No, I am not. I was under the impression that Webpack's going to produce me a CSS file that I can link to in my HTML. I conclude by your comment that I was mistaken. Where do I put the require/import? Directly in the config file for Webpack? Or in my *index.js*?

Comment: @AdamWolski Indeed, I'm not importing that file as it's now. How do I do that? Should I alter config for Webpack or should I add `import` in the starting JavaScript file? I was expecting a CSS to be produced and didn't consider linking to the SASS file at all.

Comment: @AndyJ I created an answer (not enough room here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to require somewhere your style file.

For instance, if your entry file is `main.js` you can have something like this:

```
require('./global.sass');
/* or, if you're using es6 import:

    import css from './global.sass'; 
*/
```

To clarify the process a bit: `sass-loader` process the `.sass` files and converts it to a valid `css` file (in memory, let's say so). Then, you'll have to chain (backwards) loaders to finally add the styles to your page:

A default configuration would be:

```
loaders: [
    /* ... */
    { 
        test: /\.sass$/, 
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"], 
        exclude: /node_modules/ 
    }
    /* ... */
]
```

where [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) resolves a CSS file and [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader) add a `<style>` tag at the bottom of your `<head>` with your style.

Before running that, make sure you've installed those packages:

```
npm i css-loader style-loader sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

You can, however, extract all your styles into a separated `css` file using the popular [extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

We can say, then, to summarize, that webpack does not generate a separated css file due to the `style-loader` (that adds a `style` tag to your DOM), unless you use the `extract text plugin` (very common in productions build).

Comment: Oh, so all the three loaders work in-memory? I see. I then understand the need for the plugin. What I don't get is why we have to use *style-loader* if we indent to plugin-out the CSS file and link to it? Also, I'm not sure why the plugin would be a preferred approach in production. +1 for a great formulation.

Comment: @AndyJ as far as I know, the main concern is when you a have huge app, you'll have a bunch of `<style>` tags. Some prefer a distributable file, mainly to cache/fingerprint.

Comment: @AndyJ if you use the plugin, you don't need `style-loader`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin), only to fallback purpose.

Comment: Hmm... Okay, so I get that part. Seems logical. However, I get an error now: *Unexpected token (1:5)* and when I add/remove lines in the SASS file, the numbers don't change (still 1:5). It also suggest that I need another loader. All the loaders you've suggested are installed, though. What else could I be doing wrong, please?

Comment: Correction to the error part. It only barks at the line with *font*. The others do not produce any error. Still need to verify that they do count in the file, though.

Comment: @AndyJ put a `background-color: $primary-color` in the `body` just to visually test.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Let me just try out the plugin part and I'll accept the answer. Still, can't figure out why *font: 100% $font-stack* failed on the loader. It's a valid style, isn't it? Taken from SASS's web site, too...

Comment: @AndyJ yes, it's valid. But yout font is not being changed to Helvetica?  I tried your example here and it's ok for me.

Comment: Naa, it didn't take the plugin part. I suspect that the difference is that **without** plugin, I'm using the field *loaders* (plural) and **with** plugin I have to use *loader* (singular). I've seen a cheat to use *style!css!sass" but I've been informed that it's a bad style and should be refrained from. I'll ask another question on this specifically.

Comment: @AndyJ I used it a long time ago, I'll have to check my old projects in order to remember how to use it :)

Comment: If you find time/joy to do that, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709222/how-to-specify-multiple-loaders-in-webpack-plugin). Otherwise, thanks for this one and have a nice evening.

Comment: @AndyJ  I'll check it out. And you're welcome, glad to meet you!